# Optimization of a function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I need to optimize $$f(x,y,z)= x^2-y+e^{z}$$
with the restriction $$(x-2)^2+(y-3)^2+z^2=1$$
I've tried to substitute the restriction in $f(x,y,z)$ but it seems not to work. And when trying to use the method of Lagrange multiplier, well I guess I'm not so good for systems of equations, but I couldn't find the solution. Got the system:
$$2x=2m(x-2)$$
$$-1=2m(y-3)$$
$$e^{z}=2mz$$
$$(x-2)^2+(y-3)^2+z^2=1$$
Where $m$ is the Lagrange multiplier.
Is it wrong? Is there another way to find the solution?

Comment: Observe that $e^{z}/z > 0$. So we have $e^{z}/z = 2m$. From our constraint, we note that $y \in (2, 4)$ and $x \in (1, 3)$. Otherwise, our constraint will not hold. Now observe that as $2m > 0$, we need $\frac{-1}{y-3} > 0$, and so $y \in (2, 3)$. Similarly, $\frac{2x}{x-2} > 0$, which gives us $x \in (2, 3)$. I don't have time to slog through this more, but hopefully this gets you going in a better direction. Best of luck! :-)

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't be able to find the points in the answer below by this way, but this helped me a lot for the other problems I got. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

The constraint implies that the solution is a point on a unit sphere centered at $(2;3;0)$. The points depend on inclination $\theta$ and azimut $\varphi$:

$$\begin{aligned}
x &= 2 + \sin{\theta}\cos{\varphi} \\
y &= 3 + \sin{\theta}sin{\varphi} \\
z &= cos{\theta}
\end{aligned}$$

Inserted in the original expression:

$$\begin{aligned}
f(\theta,\varphi) &= (2 + \sin{\theta}\cos{\varphi})^2 - (3 + \sin{\theta}sin{\varphi}) + e^{cos{\theta}} \\
&= 1 + 4\sin{\theta}cos{\varphi} - \sin{\theta}sin{\varphi}+ \sin^2{\theta}\cos^2{\varphi} + e^{cos{\theta}}
\end{aligned}$$

WolframAlpha finds $-1.37377$ as minimum and $7.18241$ as [maximum](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximimize%20%282%2Bsin%28a%29*cos%28b%29%29%5E2%20-%20%283%2Bsin%28a%29sin%28b%29%29%2Be%5E%28cos%28a%29%29).

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask something else?, when doing this excercises and finding points like this, is there a way to find them without using wolfram or another computing software?

Comment: The usual way is to analyze where the partial derivatives are zero. If there is no (visible) analytical solution, a numerical solution might be sufficient. Make sure that you don't get stuck in a local optimum. The numerical values sometimes help to discover the analytical solution not seen in the first place.